# Problems with validation of main page structure

Tags: html, validation, tags, w3c

I'm helping a friend work through validating a site, but at the second im stuck. I have numerous errors relating to the  head meta body and html tags. There are a few others that i can manage but i can't seem to get a grip on whats causing these... Any help would be appreciated!

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.travelsac.co.uk%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2

Comment: It gives you error messages with descriptions. Normally that should give you enough information where to look into. Always start with fixing the first error. Then validate again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><head>
```

Should be

```
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

And when you output URLs, you need to convert `&` to `&amp;`, for this you can use [htmlspecialchars](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Answer (score 1):

Your friend has put the

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

before the beginning of the head tag